# Why does my code throw an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I get a module.js:339 throw err;

I'm not sure which line or where to look to fix it. If I can get pointed in the right direction, I think I will solve it. I'm searching for the wrong information and I can'get seem to figure out why and how and what to do to fix the error.

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
 id: ObjectId,
 firstName: String,
 lastName: String,
 email: { type: String, unique: true },
 password: String,
}));

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.locals.pretty = true;

// conenct to mongo
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/auth');

// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(req, re6s) {
 res.render('index.jade');
});

app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
 res.render('register.jade');
});

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
 var user = new User({
  firstName: req.body.firstName,
  lastName: req.body.lastName,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password
 });
 user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
   var err = "Something bad happened! Try again!";
   if (err.code === 11000) {
    error = "That email is already taken. Try another.";
   }
   res.render("register.jade", { error: error });
  } else {
   res.redirect("/dashboard");
  }
 });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
 res.render('login.jade');
});

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
 res.render('dashboard.jade');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Full ERROR message:

```
>node app.js
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mechart\Desktop\auth\app.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
```

Comment: If you look at the error stack trace you should eventually find a line mentioning one of your files (if the stack calls arent too deep). Other than that what does the full error message say?

Comment: Yeah, I posted it, but I'm real new...trying to navigate around programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Can't find module 'Express'` means that the express module is not properly installed at a path that is reachable from your project.  You need to install that module with NPM.  Same with any other modules you are using in this project.  It should be as simple as changing to the directory of your app and then issuing this command in the console:

```
npm install express
```

---

You also have another error that should be fixed.

**Duplicate variable definition causes error handling not to work**

In this code, you have an argument named `err` and then you also have `var err`.  That will make it so your argument is overridden by the locally declared `var` and your error handling will not work:

Change this:

```
user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        var err = "Something bad happened! Try again!";
        if (err.code === 11000) {
            error = "That email is already taken. Try another.";
        }
        res.render("register.jade", { error: error });
    } else {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }
});
```

to this:

```
user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        // change this variable name to errMsg in each place you use it
        var errMsg = "Something bad happened! Try again!";
        if (err.code === 11000) {
            errMsg = "That email is already taken. Try another.";
        }
        res.render("register.jade", { error: errMsg });
    } else {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }
});
```

Comment: I changed var err to error and that did it for me alongside npm install jade. G